# Where should I save the "int" type in the heap structure?

Tags: python

```
def interpretDTREE(d) :
    """pre: d  is a declaration represented as a DTREE:
       DTREE ::=  ["int", ID, ETREE]
       post:  heap is updated with  d
    """

    operator = d[0]
    if operator == "int" : # declaration ["int", ID, ETREE]
        id = d[1]
        typeID = ["int", id]
        etree = d[2]
        rval = interpretETREE(etree)
        declare (activeNS(), typeID, rval)   
    else : # error
        crash("invalid DTREE")
```

After adding `typeID = ["int", id]`, I get the error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Heap Structure:

```
heap : { (HANDLE : NAMESPACE)+ }
```

where  `HANDLE` = a string, e.g.,  `'h1'`, and `NAMESPACE` = a dictionary that maps var names to ints or to handles.  Also contains a "parents" link to more-global vars.

Why I want to add "int" in the typeID?
Because I want to declare the variable with the type "int", However, I do not know where should I store the "int" in the heap.

Comment: It's not clear what any of this is supposed to do or what your data structures are supposed to look like. Are you implementing an interpreter? It sounds like this question requires so much context from the rest of your program that you're the only one here with enough information to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put a mutable object into a dictionary key; all values in a key *must* be immutable and hashable.

Use a tuple instead:

```
typeID = ("int", id)
```

Tuples are immutable sequences, lists are mutable.